# How to record to record to a database with one-to-many relationship?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-3.7

I am trying to do a small project, but have some difficulties around database structure in SQLAlchemy. I have two database models (code below).

1. User model is created and added to the database during the registration form.
2. Then I need to find a way to add Clients for loggedin user from his profile.

Question:
How do I do that? I need to create a record specifically for the logged-in user. So that when I display them (his clients)- they are only displayed to that specific user.

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    **tablename** = 'user'

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
company_name = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=False)
email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
clients = db.relationship('Client', backref='invoice_clients', lazy='dynamic')
```

class Client(db.Model):
    **tablename** = 'client'

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
client_name = db.Column(db.String(140))
client_company = db.Column(db.String(140))
client_email = db.Column(db.String(140))
invoice_amount = db.Column(db.Integer)
service_description = db.Column(db.String)
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

I expect that the when a user adds a client from his profile page - it will be recorded in the database only for him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I believe you have the `backref` parameter backwards. That is the property you can use on the referenced objects to "get back" to the current class. So it should probably look like this:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    clients = db.relationship('Client', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')
```

As to your question about adding clients for a specific user, there are two ways you can approach it. You can do it manually:

```
# Or flask_login, or whatever you're using for user management
from flask_security import current_user

new_client = Client(client_name="Lancelot", user_id=current_user.id)
db.session.add(new_client)
db.session.commit()
```

Or you can simply use SQLAlchemy to append the client to your user. The declared foreign key will cause the id to be assigned automatically:

```
from flask_security import current_user

new_client = Client(client_name="Sir Bedivere")
current_user.clients.append(new_client)
db.session.commit()
```